# Euler chart without function in event

Tags: javascript, json, angular, highcharts, venn-diagram

I am trying to create this chart using highcharts. I may have succeed partially.

[image: Euler Chart]

Here is my fiddle where I am trying.
`Fiddle Link`[JS Fiddle Link here](https://jsfiddle.net/not_a_genius/4bzus1g3/1/)

1. Please help me to create this chart.
2. Also as you can see I am using load event which uses function but for some reason I don't have to use a function. So can this chart be created without function. It doesn't matter what you use. There is no animation requirement or any event requirement. I am using that only because I was not aware of doing it any differently.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Kumar, The only thing you miss is the connector lines, right?

Comment: @ppotaczek, Yes that is one thing for sure. But I am trying to write this configuration in JSON and send to Client side which will be then executed by Highcharts, so I have written function as String and that is not being executed on client. So either I need to do this without function or make the function run on client. A help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is a problematic case. Unfortunately I don't see a way to create exactly the same chart without custom functions.